# Access node fields in hook_node_grants

Tags: 6, users

In `hook_node_grants()` I want to check if user ID is equal to a node's field value, But there is only two arguments: *$account* and *$op*

How can I access the node object that is being checked for grants?

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to this would be to implement [hook_node_api](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) that checks the current $user's permissions to the loaded field then does something.

```
function custom_module_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  //get the current user
  global $user;

  switch ($op) {
    case 'load':
      //do some logic with $node and with the current $user's roles
    break;

    //(optional)add other cases for other operations

    default:
    break;
  }
}
```

alternatively you can try [template_preprocess_node](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_node/6)

```
function theme_name_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  global $user;
  $node = $variables['node'];

  //do some stuff with $node and $user
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately these don't allow to prevent a node from listing and denying access to node before loading

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem.  It won't control access to the node.